# current user details are getting mapped to all the posts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, redux

current user detail are getting mapped to all the posts. As each post is created by a unique user but all the displaying posts throwing current user name and email. using the firebase 9
tryin to store name and email in firebase authentication, but seems not to be working for me, also I am a newbie.

This is the login I have created

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {
  createUserWithEmailAndPassword,
  getAuth,
  signInWithEmailAndPassword,
  updateProfile,
} from "firebase/auth";
import { login } from "./features/userSlice";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";

function Login() {
  const [Email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [Name, setName] = useState("");
  const [Password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const auth = getAuth();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const loginToApp = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, Email, Password)
      .then((userCredential) => {
        const user = userCredential.user;

        dispatch(
          login({
            email: Email,
            uid: user.uid,
            userName: Name,
          })
        );
      })
      .catch((error1) => {
        alert(error1.message);
      });
  };
  const Regsiter = () => {
    if (!Name) {
      return alert("Please enter you full name");
    }

    createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, Email, Password)
      .then((userCredential) => {
        const user = userCredential.user;
        updateProfile(user, {
          displayName: Name,
          email: Email,
        });

        dispatch(
          login({
            uid: user.uid,
            displayName: Name,
            email: Email,
          })
        );
      })
      .catch((error1) => {
        alert(error1.message);
      });

    
  };
  return (
    <div className=" flex flex-col items-center mt-16">
      <img
        className=" w-1/6"
        src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/01/LinkedIn_Logo.svg/2560px-LinkedIn_Logo.svg.png"
        alt=""
      />

      <form className="flex flex-col w-64 space-y-3 mb-16 mt-4">
        <input
          onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
          className="py-2 pl-2   rounded-md border-2  border-l-black border-t-black border-b-gray-500 border-r-gray-500 focus:bg-gray-50"
          type="text "
          placeholder="Full Name(required if registering)"
        />
        <input
          onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
          className="py-2 pl-2 rounded-md border-2  border-l-black border-t-black border-b-gray-500 border-r-gray-500 focus:bg-gray-50  "
          type="email"
          placeholder="Email"
        />
        <input
          onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
          className="py-2 pl-2 rounded-md border-2  border-l-black border-t-black border-b-gray-500 border-r-gray-500 focus:bg-gray-50"
          type="password"
          placeholder="Password"
        />
        <button
          onClick={loginToApp}
          className=" text-white bg-blue-600 py-2 rounded-md   shadow-gray-500 shadow-md  click"
        >
          Sign In
        </button>
        <p className="block text-center">
          Not a member?{" "}
          <span onClick={Regsiter} className=" text-blue-600   cursor-pointer ">
            Register Now
          </span>
        </p>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Login;
```

This is the feed I am using

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import CreateIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Create";
import ImageIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Image";
import SubscriptionsIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Subscriptions";
import EventNoteIcon from "@mui/icons-material/EventNote";
import CalendarViewDayIcon from "@mui/icons-material/CalendarViewDay";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { db } from "./firebase";
import {
  collection,
  getDocs,
  orderBy,
  doc,
  query,
  setDoc,
  onSnapshot,
} from "firebase/firestore";
import { serverTimestamp } from "firebase/firestore";
import Post from "./posts";
import { selectUser } from "./features/userSlice";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";

function Feeds() {
  const [displayNamee, setdisplayName] = useState();
  const [emaile, setemail] = useState();
  const user = useSelector(selectUser);
  const [enteredText, setEnteredText] = useState("");
  const [Postfromfirebase, setPostfromfirebase] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const auth = getAuth();
      const user = auth.currentUser;
      if (user !== null) {
        // The user object has basic properties such as display name, email, etc.
        setdisplayName(user.displayName);
        setemail(user.email);
      }

      const colref = collection(db, "coll");
      const q = query(colref, orderBy("timestamp", "desc"));
      onSnapshot(q, (snapshot) => {
        snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
          // console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());

          setPostfromfirebase(
            snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
              id: doc.id,
              data: doc.data(),
            }))
          );
        });
      });

      
    })();
  }, []);

  const Submitted = async (a) => {
    a.preventDefault();

    setEnteredText("");
    const posts = collection(db, "coll");
    setDoc(doc(posts), {
      Name: { displayNamee },
      Learningreact: { emaile },
      Postss: enteredText,
      timestamp: serverTimestamp(),
    });

    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "coll"));
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
      setPostfromfirebase(
        querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
          id: doc.id,
          data: doc.data(),
        }))
      );
    });
  };
  return (
    <>
      <div className="   flex  flex-col basis-4/6 ">
        <div className=" bg-white rounded-xl ">
          <form
            id="formm"
            action=""
            className="  border flex flex-row  justify-between mt-2 mb-5 mr-4 py-4 p ml-3 bg-white p-2 border-gray-300 rounded-full   items-center"
          >
            <CreateIcon />
            <input
              type="text"
              className=" flex-1  px-4  focus:outline-none  "
              value={enteredText}
              onChange={(e) => setEnteredText(e.target.value)}
            />

            <button onClick={Submitted} className=" hidden " type="submit">
              Send
            </button>
          </form>
          <div className=" flex flex-row    justify-between px-12 pb-4 ">
            <div className=" cursor-pointer hover:bg-slate-200 p-4  rounded-full text-blue-400 flex flex-row items-center">
              <ImageIcon />
              <h3 className="  text-gray-500 font-semibold text-black pl-2">
                Photo
              </h3>
            </div>
            <div className=" cursor-pointer hover:bg-slate-200 rounded-full p-4 text-orange-300 flex flex-row items-center">
              <SubscriptionsIcon />
              <h3 className="text-black text-gray-500 font-semibold pl-2">
                Video
              </h3>
            </div>
            <div className=" cursor-pointer hover:bg-slate-200 rounded-full  p-4 text-gray-400 flex flex-row items-center">
              <EventNoteIcon />
              <h3 className="text-black text-gray-500 font-semibold pl-2">
                Event
              </h3>
            </div>
            <div className=" cursor-pointer hover:bg-slate-200 rounded-full p-4 text-green-900 flex flex-row items-center">
              <CalendarViewDayIcon />
              <h3 className=" text-black text-gray-500 font-semibold pl-2">
                Write article
              </h3>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        {Postfromfirebase.map(
          ({ id, data: { userName, Learningreact, Postss } }) => (
            <Post
              key={id}
              names={displayNamee}
              description={emaile}
              postdata={Postss}
            />
          )
        )}
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default Feeds;
```

Answer (score 0):

`displayNamee` and `emaile` are the local state variables that `Feeds` saved as the current authenticated user. I see that `data.userName` and `data.Learningreact` are unused though and it seems likely these `data` values are the values you intended to pass to `Post` as props.

```
{Postfromfirebase.map(
  ({ id, data: { userName, Learningreact, Postss } }) => (
    <Post
      key={id}
      names={userName}
      description={Learningreact}
      postdata={Postss}
    />
  )
)}
```

Comment: I did tried this, but getting the following error: Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {emaile}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead. I tried rendering  by commenting out emaile, it simply renders  the page but does not return names as well. Any more help is appreciated.

Comment: @GoutamSachdeva I see. It seems you may have nested the values you want to render a level *too* deep, or I'm incorrect and you do actually want to reference a user name and email, etc. from local state. Where exactly is this issue happening in the code? Please edit your post to include these new details and the code stacktrace for the error.